# The pattern that allows you to switch to the registration route does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

help solve the problem.

I am trying to allow the use of the registration route without prior authentication, but my solution does not work and I get a response with the status 401 unauthorized.
But my solution for opening access to everyone for the GET method of access is working fine.

I use Spring boot 3.0.2, Spring security 6.0.2

The configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .cors()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new AccessDeniedExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

The controller code of this route:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> registration(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName,
                                                @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password) {
        if (firstName.isBlank() || lastName.isBlank() || email.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if (!EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email)) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }

        Optional<Account> accountOptional = accountRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (accountOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        Account account = Account.builder()
                .firstName(firstName)
                .lastName(lastName)
                .email(email)
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(password))
                .build();

        account = accountRepository.save(account);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(account);
    }
}
```

When I send a request, I get a 401 response code, which means that my solution for allowing access to the route for everyone is not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBGRK.png)

I tried replacing the route pattern with:
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration") -> .requestMatchers("/registration")
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration") -> .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration/**")
etc.

Debug logs:

```
2023-02-21T23:12:30.447+05:00  INFO 1424 --- [           main] r.e.p.itplanetstep1.ItPlanetApplication  : Started ItPlanetApplication in 6.267 seconds (process running for 6.619)
2023-02-21T23:12:30.449+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2023-02-21T23:12:30.450+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2023-02-21T23:12:49.797+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request POST /registration
2023-02-21T23:12:49.804+05:00  INFO 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.804+05:00  INFO 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.804+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@7866fe3e
2023-02-21T23:12:49.804+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@2e2c9e24
2023-02-21T23:12:49.804+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@6164b3a2
2023-02-21T23:12:49.805+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator
2023-02-21T23:12:49.805+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected SessionFlashMapManager
2023-02-21T23:12:49.805+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-02-21T23:12:49.811+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2eb3c530
2023-02-21T23:12:49.811+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springSecurityFilterChain'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.813+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@544733a4, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@522f74a1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@60658389, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7c919e1e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1c41931a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3cf7433e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3e563293, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6a905513, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@59700156, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1399ad68, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2e27325d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@3c717ef2]] (1/1)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.815+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /registration
2023-02-21T23:12:49.816+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.816+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.818+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.819+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.822+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.823+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.823+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.823+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Did not process authentication request since failed to find username and password in Basic Authorization header
2023-02-21T23:12:49.823+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.823+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.832+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.836+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.837+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.839+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.839+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.839+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.840+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6b70625a]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.854+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authenticationController'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.854+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to ru.earwarm.programms.itplanetstep1.controllers.AuthenticationController#registration(String, String, String, String)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.855+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6b70625a] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1241/0x00000008017df218@47dc601e
2023-02-21T23:12:49.855+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /registration
2023-02-21T23:12:49.858+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/registration", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.861+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authenticationController'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.861+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to ru.earwarm.programms.itplanetstep1.controllers.AuthenticationController#registration(String, String, String, String)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.863+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-02-21T23:12:49.896+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<ru.earwarm.programms.itplanetstep1.models.Account> ru.earwarm.programms.itplanetstep1.controllers.AuthenticationController.registration(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): Required request parameter 'firstName' for method parameter type String is not present
2023-02-21T23:12:49.907+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.908+05:00  WARN 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'firstName' for method parameter type String is not present]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.908+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2023-02-21T23:12:49.908+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-02-21T23:12:49.909+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST, headers={masked}
2023-02-21T23:12:49.909+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.910+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2eb3c530
2023-02-21T23:12:49.910+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@3f81b133
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@544733a4, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@522f74a1, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@60658389, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7c919e1e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1c41931a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3cf7433e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3e563293, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6a905513, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@59700156, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1399ad68, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2e27325d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@3c717ef2]] (1/1)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.920+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.921+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.922+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@3f81b133]]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.927+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 matching mappings: [{ [/error]}, { [/error], produces [text/html]}]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.928+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2023-02-21T23:12:49.929+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-02-21T23:12:49.929+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@3f81b133]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@5379ab74
2023-02-21T23:12:49.929+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.929+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.930+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:691) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:295) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:372) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
2023-02-21T23:12:49.935+05:00 TRACE 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@3f81b133
2023-02-21T23:12:49.936+05:00 DEBUG 1424 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for further output
```

My English not so be good.

Comment: `can't understand why the pattern that allows you to switch to the web application registration route does not work` what do you mean by ”switch to”? Please enable spring security debug logs and post your logs in full so that we can see what errors you are getting. And also please post what your request looks like.

Comment: My English not so be good. I reformulated the description of the problem.

Comment: Could you please enable debug logs and post your full logs including the error

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I can't provide logs with an error, since I don't have an error.

Comment: the 401 is your "error" so to speak, the logs will tell you why you get a 401

Comment: I have published debugging logs, but I cannot understand why my request matcher pattern for allowing access to everyone on the registration route does not work.

Comment: Read the logs here is your error `Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<ru.earwarm.programms.itplanetstep1.models.Account> ru.earwarm.programms.itplanetstep1.controllers.AuthenticationController.registration(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): Required request parameter 'firstName' for method parameter type String is not present`

Comment: So we need to look at your request, because you are doing a faulty request

Comment: I specifically execute an erroneous request, hoping to get the 400 bad request status, but instead I get 401 unauthorized. The request can be viewed in the image below the controller code.

Comment: then you should write that

Comment: can you please add `.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/error").permitAll()` to your security configuration and read this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by setting the spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled to true setting in application.yml file.

[@Toerktumlare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1840146/toerktumlare) thanks.